# Combining two conditions: Vowel and a space

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am trying to check for two conditions,

1. The string should contain a vowel.
2. The string should contain a space.

Here is what I am writing:

```
$reg = "/(?=.*(\s)) (?=.*(a|e|i|o|u))/";
```

But on running:

```
if ( preg_match($reg,"kka "))
        echo "YES.";
    else
        echo "NO.";
```

I am getting `NO`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: NO, it's not working https://regex101.com/r/KwdUrF/1

Comment: Just do one check per criteria. Easier to do and to maintain.

Comment: Good suggestion, ORing and ANDing becomes more dangerous. :)

Comment: Looks like you just need to 1.) drop the space in between your conditions 2.) add [start anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).  And you can replace one lookahead with normal matching [like this](https://www.regex101.com/r/vD8mqJ/2) if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((?:.*)[aeiouAEIOU]+(?:.*)[ ]+(?:.*))|(?:.*)[ ]+((?:.*)[aeiouAEIOU]+(?:.*))
```

You can try with this

[Explnation](https://regex101.com/r/R5og46/5)

Comment: could you please check now ?

Comment: It works, thanks. But it can be minimized,   I think.

Comment: Although you answer work, but this is the optimized solution: `/(?=.*\s+)(?=.*[aeiou]+)/`

Comment: After making it case insensitive, where does it fail? works fine here: https://regex101.com/r/KwdUrF/3

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct way to use lookaheads:

```
^((?=.*\s.*).)((?=.*[aeiou].*).).*$
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

If you want an option which does not involve using a regex would be to remove spaces/vowels from the input string and verify that the resulting length has decreased.

```
$input = "kka ";
if (strlen(preg_replace("/\s/", "", $input)) < strlen($input) &&
    strlen(preg_replace("/[aeiouAEIOU]/", "", $input)) < strlen($input)) {
    echo "both conditions satisfied"
else {
    echo "both conditions not satisfied"
}
```

Comment: The thing is why didn't my answer work? I don't want my original string to be modified or copied

Comment: Any significance of `.)` in `((?=.*\s.*).)`. I am new to regex, thanks for the help.

Comment: A lookahead is an _assertion_.  This lookahead asserts once, at the start of the string, that what follows is anything followed by a single whitespace, followed by anything.  This is what is known as a "tempered" dot.  Youbcan read more about this here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution using `preg_replace` and `strpos` functions:

```
$str = " aa k";

if (($replaced = preg_replace("/[^aeiou ]/i", "", $str)) && strlen($replaced) >= 2 
    && strpos($replaced, " ") !== false) {
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
```